# How to have an iframe that change the URL when link are clicked?

Tags: iframe, hyperlink

I'm using an Help Desk software that doesn't allow me to put a script in the page. I'm unable to find the source of the page as is Laravel programmed so I don't see any physic page to edit.

I need add the live chat script to the Help Desk so I'm including the Help Desk page in a iframe with the following string:

```
<div class="resp-container">
<iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://helpdesk.domain.ext/page" gesture="media"  allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Now this will show at 100% the content in the iframe.
Before the div closing I have the live chat code and works.

The issue is that when the user are on the iframe page: ex address: `domain.ext/iframepage.html` and click a link in the iframe, the URL in the browser will not showing the specific page address of the clicked URL.

There are some code I can add in the iframe to the browser URL change when a link inside the iframe is clicked, without loose the view in the  iframe?

Thanks.

I tried to add some code in the iframe page as I cannot edit the links showed in the iframe, I don't manage them.. but user when click a link, will see the iframe content changing but the URL still be the same.

I need have dynamic URL so user can copy the address of the article they are seeing.

Comment: Cross-origin restrictions likely make what you want to do impossible. For Laravel, chances are most of your site's HTML is in the `resources/views` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this if the app in the iframe is on a different domain, is to setup a proxy server to inject extra JavaScriot into the page as it passes through. In which case you might as well inject the chat script.